# Adiabatic compressibility factor of ethyl alcohol

Tags: thermodynamics

I am looking for a source where I can find the adiabatic compressibility factor of ethyl alcohol at approximately 15 degrees Celsius. I have found the compressibility factor at 20 degrees. Is there maybe a way to convert this to the desirable temperature?

Comment: Maybe in Perry's :)

Comment: I could calculate values using REFPROP, NIST Standard Reference Database 23, Version 9. What temperature and pressure do you need? Exactly 15 °C and 1 bar?

Comment: The Isothermal compressibility at 20 degrees C is given in the CRC.  And there is an article "Adiabatic compressibility and structure of aqueous solutions of ethyl alcohol" that includes measurements of pure ethyl alcohol in AIP.  It is free online, "If you have an individual subscription, a subscription provided by one of AIP's Member Societies, have claimed access to a Conference Proceeding, or have made an individual purchase".  I don't know if either of these solutions would be helpful or easier than what has already been suggested.

Comment: @Loong 15.5 degrees and 1 bar, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A calculation using the [NIST Reference Fluid Thermodynamic and Transport Properties Database (REFPROP) – NIST Standard Reference Database 23, Version 9](http://www.nist.gov/srd/nist23.cfm), and assuming a temperature of $T=15.5\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and a pressure of $p=1\ \mathrm{bar}$, yields an isothermal compressibility of ethanol of
$$\varkappa_T=-\frac1V\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T=1.0795\times10^{-9}\ \mathrm{Pa^{-1}}$$
and an adiabatic (or isentropic) compressibility of
$$\varkappa_S=-\frac1V\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_S=9.1749\times10^{-10}\ \mathrm{Pa^{-1}}$$
The number of digits is the default setting of the software and does not necessarily correspond to the number of significant digits.

By way of comparison, the results for a temperature of $T=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and a pressure of $p=1\ \mathrm{bar}$ are
$$\varkappa_T=1.1130\times10^{-9}\ \mathrm{Pa^{-1}}$$
and
$$\varkappa_S=9.4729\times10^{-10}\ \mathrm{Pa^{-1}}$$
The data in “Pressure and Temperature Dependence of Liquid Density”, in *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 90th Edition (CD-ROM Version 2010),* David R. Lide, ed., CRC Press/Taylor and Francis, Boca Raton, FL include a value of $\varkappa_T=1.119\times10^{-9}\ \mathrm{Pa^{-1}}$ for $T=20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. Therefore, it seems a likely supposition that the corresponding calculation result of $\varkappa_T=1.1130\times10^{-9}\ \mathrm{Pa^{-1}}$ is reasonable but the number of digits is excessive.